# How to correctly align divs within a div

Tags: html, css

With my containers aligned using the grid method within the body. Can I apply the grid display to the .main container and then arrange the divs found within the .main container? Is there a more efficient way of organizing that. I've tried the following code in an attempt to evenly organize the 6 divs within the .main container. Every time I reload the browser, the 6 divs seem to overflow from the .main container looking super odd and including the option to scroll, which I'm not after. Oddly enough if I right click in chrome and press inspect, and close the inspect window they align quite well. But if I refresh the browser it reverts back to the overflow.

```css
body {
  color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 75% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 75%;
  grid-gap: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #222831;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 0;
  background-color: #222831;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.freeSpace {
  background-color: #222831;
  margin: 3px;
}

.main div {
  background-color: #393e46;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Concept">
  <meta name="description" content="Concept">
  <meta name="author" content="Concept">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>concept</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="plumbing">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="electrical">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="homeAppliances">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="roofing">
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flooring">
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="homeAutomation">
      <p>6</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="freeSpace">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Looks ok to me in Chrome

Comment: hmm thanks for confirming that for me. might just be something odd going on with my pc then.